# @Queryin through list to find teh max

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

( Im not sure if this is possible )
I have a One to Many relationship between A and B ( Multiple Bs for each A modelled using @OneToMany).
In my JpaRepository for B, I want to write a custom Query so as to return a single B which has the highest value for a specific attribute.
Something like:

```
@Query( value="SELECT a.list_of_Bs.//max(b.version)//  FROM A a WHERE a.id = :a_param" )
B findLargestB(A a_param) ;
```

How will I do max(b.version). ( How will I extract the single B from the list which has the highest version attribute )

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column/7745635#7745635). Have a look. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

#### METHOD 1:

Use `@Query` with `nativeQuery = true` in the JPA repository class of `B`

Here, I will use `ORDER BY b.version DESC` with `LIMIT 1` in order to get the max version of B.

But unfortunately, currently, there is no way to limit records in `JPQL`. So that, if you want to limit it to 1 record only, you must add `nativeQuery = true` to `@Query` annotation.

The native query (for readability):

```
SELECT 
    b.* 
FROM 
    A a 
INNER JOIN B b ON b.a_id = a.id 
WHERE a.id = :a_id 
ORDER BY b.version DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

**Solution with the above query**:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT b.* FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON b.a_id = a.id WHERE a.id = :a_id ORDER BY b.version DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
B findLargestB(Integer a_id) ;
```

#### METHOD 2:

Use "Spring Data Query Method"

You can use `findFirst` or `findTop` in combination with `order by ... desc`

**Solution**:

```
B findTopByAOrderByVersionDesc(A a);
B findFirstByAOrderByVersionDesc(A a);
```